# Using synchronous operations in an asynchronous controller

Tags: c#, wcf, asynchronous, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm using VS 2013 with the 4.5.1 framework and MVC5.

I have a web service which contains methods that are called from the client MVC controllers. Most of them are asynchronous and a few are synchronous. **I am getting design time compile errors in my client controllers for the ones which are synchronous. Can anybody tell me why?**

Here is my code for an async and sync operation on my backend web service.

```
public class CategoryController : AsyncController
```

**ASYNC**

```
public async Task<Category> GetCategoryIDAsync(Int16 categoryid)
        {
            try
            {
                using (YeagerTechEntities DbContext = new YeagerTechEntities())
                {
                    DbContext.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
                    DbContext.Database.Connection.Open();

                    var categoryEntity = await DbContext.Categories.Include("Projects").FirstOrDefaultAsync(f => f.CategoryID == categoryid);


                    Category category = null;
                    if (categoryEntity != null)
                    {
                        category = new Category();
                        category.CategoryID = categoryEntity.CategoryID;
                        category.Description = categoryEntity.Description;
                        category.Projects = categoryEntity.Projects;
                    }
                    else
                        throw new Exception("Category " + categoryid + " not found!");

                    return category;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
```

**SYNC**
            public void AddCategory(Category cat)
            {
                try
                {
                    using (YeagerTechEntities DbContext = new YeagerTechEntities())
                    {

```
                    Category category = new Category();

                    category.Description = cat.Description;

                    DbContext.Categories.Add(category);
                    DbContext.SaveChanges();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
```

Here is the code on the front-end in my controller.

**ASYNC**

```
 [Authorize(Roles = "Admin, AdminStage")]
 public async Task<ActionResult> SelectCategoryProjects([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request, string intCategoryID)
 {
            if (Session["Culture"] != null)
                System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(Session["Culture"].ToString());

            try
            {
                YeagerTechWcfService.Project[] projectList = await db.GetProjectByCategoryIDAsync(Convert.ToInt16(intCategoryID));

                var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                var result = new ContentResult();
                serializer.MaxJsonLength = Int32.MaxValue;
                result.Content = serializer.Serialize(projectList.ToDataSourceResult(request));
                result.ContentType = "application/json";

                return result;
 }
```

**SYNC**

```
[HttpPost]
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin, AdminStage")]
public ActionResult UpsertCategory([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request, Category cat, Boolean blnInsert)
{
            if (TryUpdateModel(cat))
            {
                try
                {
                    if (blnInsert)
                        db.AddCategory(cat);
                    else
                        db.EditCategory(cat);

                    return Json(new[] { cat }.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState));
}
```

I get the design time compile error of the typical "The best overloaded method match" "Has some invalid arguments" which is easy enough to understand.

If I click the "AddCategory" method, there is a blue underscore which states:

Generate method stub for "AddCategory" in YeagerTech.YeagerTechWcfService.YeagerTechWcfServiceClient"

If I do that, it adds an internal method in my Reference.cs file that the proxy generated when adding the service reference with a typical "Not implemented" error in the body of the method when it gets created. However, there are already two methods each for the AddCategory and EditCategory methods in my Reference.cs file. If I comply with adding the stub, it complains that the method already exists and rightfully so.

Here are the two methods that got generated in the proxy. The first one is sync and the second one is async:

```
[System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="http://tempuri.org/IYeagerTechWcfService/AddCategory", ReplyAction="http://tempuri.org/IYeagerTechWcfService/AddCategoryResponse")]
void AddCategory(YeagerTech.YeagerTechWcfService.Category cat);

[System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="http://tempuri.org/IYeagerTechWcfService/AddCategory", ReplyAction="http://tempuri.org/IYeagerTechWcfService/AddCategoryResponse")]
System.Threading.Tasks.Task AddCategoryAsync(YeagerTech.YeagerTechWcfService.Category cat);
```

**What do I need to do in order to resolve this?**

Comment: Any chance at all there are two `Category` classes walking around?  PS - is this actually beneficial? `catch (Exception) {throw;}`

Comment: The methods in the model project are of namespace: "YeagerTechModel.Category". When coming back from the service, in order to retrieve the data, I need to specify the following code: "YeagerTechWcfService.Category[] categoryList = await db.GetCategoriesAsync();" If I try and use this code "YeagerTechModel.Category[] = await db.GetCategoriesAsync();", I get the error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'YeagerTech.YeagerTechWcfService.Category[]' to 'YeagerTechModel.Category[]'. If you notice, I did state that the proxy generated the above posts code in which to hold the data. Any ideas?

Comment: Often times if two classes are in the same hierarchy and can be converted one to the other 1 at a time, arrays cannot be converted so automatically.  Note: 2 classes with the same name in the same hierarchy is just flat out bad and wrong, so they shouldn't *be* related in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing `AsyncController` to `Controller`. `AsyncController` is no longer required.

Comment: I made the change as suggested. However, I am getting the msg: The best overloaded method match for 'YeagerTech.YeagerTechWcfService.YeagerTechWcfServiceClient.AddCategory(YeagerTech.YeagerTechWcfService.Category)' has some invalid arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by changing the parameter coming into the method.

Before, it was of type: "YeagerTechModel.Category". I changed it to "YeagerTechWcdfService.Category" (which the proxy generated) and that solved the design time compile error.

Thanks to both of you in pointing me in the right direction :)

Here is the code that I updated it to:

```
[HttpPost]
        [Authorize(Roles = "Admin, AdminStage")]
        public ActionResult UpsertCategory([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request, YeagerTechWcfService.Category cat, Boolean blnInsert)
        {
            if (TryUpdateModel(cat))
            {
                try
                {
                    if (blnInsert)
                        db.AddCategory(cat);
                    else
                        db.EditCategory(cat);

                    return Json(new[] { cat }.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState));
                }
```